# Visibility of properties in derived classes (C#)

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, abstract-class

I have been making some hamfisted attempts to apply correct OOP principles to my project.  I have an abstract class called DocumentSection, and several classes deriving from it (DocumentSectionView, DocumentSectionText, etc).  Similarly I have an abstract class (DocAction) with several classes deriving from it (DocumentActionReplaceByTag, DocumentSectionAppend, etc). Each DocumentSection has a DocumentAction within it.

My understanding of all this inheritance business is that by specifying a 'DocumentAction', this would allow any of those derived classes to be put in its place, and that any properties/methods from the base class would be available, as well as any specified in the concrete class I instantiate.  So in the below example, I expected to be able to see the PerformAction method (leaving the virtual/override keywords out of the mix for now).  And it is available.

However, because I went v.DocAction = new DocumentActionReplaceByTag();, I would also have expected my ReplaceActionFindText property to be visible.

Obviously I've got it wrong somewhere - any comments appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DocumentSectionView v = new DocumentSectionView();
        v.DocAction = new DocumentActionReplaceByTag();

        // would like to go:
        //v.DocAction.ReplaceActionFindText...

        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}    
public abstract class DocumentSection
{
    public abstract string GetContent();
    public DocumentAction DocAction { get; set; }
}
public class DocumentSectionView : DocumentSection
{
    public string ViewPath { get; set; }
    public dynamic ViewModel { get; set; }

    public override string GetContent()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}    
public abstract class DocumentAction
{
    void PerformAction(StringBuilder sb, string content);
}
public class DocumentActionReplaceByTag : DocumentAction
{
    public string ReplaceActionFindText { get; set; }
    public void PerformAction(StringBuilder sb, string content)
    {
        sb.Replace(ReplaceActionFindText, content);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I've marked an answer as correct, but thought I'd add the fruits of my further thought on this matter for those coming across this later:

a) As pointed out, my intentions were broadly right but my method wrong.  Setting the 'Action's property from the Main method was not correct.  In all cases, a a DocumentActionReplaceByTag requires the FindText so I placed it in the constructor:

```
    public DocumentActionReplaceByTag(string replaceActionFindText)
    {
        this.ReplaceActionFindText = replaceActionFindText;
    }
```

From then on, a constructor with 0 arguments will rightly fail, and prevent a case where the action is executed but no findtext is specified.

b) Polymorphism works fine now, because my extra property findtext has been populated, and running PerformAction will run correctly regardless of the action type.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  So, what's the 'OOP correct' way of specifying in the DocumentSection that any kind of DocAction can be specified.  The goal was to move from my old method (discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242520/correct-oop-practice-for-class-properties-tied-by-logic) to using polymorphism to call action.GetContent(); on my DocAction to run whatever the appropriate getcontent action is.  But to do that, I need to set properties (like the ReplaceActionText) that are specific to that action.  The cast below was commented as being non-ideal - is casting the only approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are assigning your derived class to a property with the type of the base class only the methods and properties of the base class will be available. And this makes sense since you could have assigned *any* instance of a class that derives from the base class - so any derived methods cannot be used in this context.

This is one of the OOP principles - your derived class instances may be used as an instance of a base class (but not the other way round)

**Edit:**

To elaborate on the solution proposed by @sll to cast to a particular derived class type: Don't do it! It is a workaround but not in the interest of the overall design.

If you have to cast to a derived type then you are violating the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) meaning that any derived type should be usable in place of the base type - that's clearly not the case if you need a specific cast.

Rethink your design - do you really need a property with the base class type and if so are the methods currently only in one particular derived type better off being in the base type as well?

Comment: Thanks Brokenglass.  In the link I put above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242520/correct-oop-practice-for-class-properties-tied-by-logic) I was trying to avoid having properties that didn't relate to a given purpose.  Eg one action might require a path/file name, while another action might require a 'textcontent' property.  Bundling both those into the base class doesn't sound like the 'right way'?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `v` reference type is  of the `DocumentSectionView` which is not aware of methods of the `DocumentActionReplaceByTag`  class even underlying instance is of `DocumentActionReplaceByTag` as you've assigned it. You need to cast it to be able accesing derived class members:

```
((DocumentActionReplaceByTag)v.DocAction).ReplaceActionFindText
```

Also in some cases this is pretty fine when underlying instance could not be casted so some part of code should be skipped, then you can use exception-safe way of casting using [as operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
var typedAction = v.DocAction as DocumentActionReplaceByTag;
if (typedAction != null)
{
   // accessing the typedAction.ReplaceActionFindText property
}
```

My suggestions are only to help you understand C# side of question, regarding overall design and approach please see BrokenGlass's answer.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a cast will let him do what he wants

Comment: this would defeat the purpose of this design though

Comment: @BrokenGlass : sorry I didn't get the point regarding the current design, could you clarify please? What is right soltion for this design? I just see that code in the method `main()` does not makes sense since benefits of OOP are not used when assigning derived class instance to base reference

Comment: If he has a property with a type of the base class you should never have to cast to a more derived class type - this violates the Liskov substitution principle and is a code smell in general (to put it mildly)

Comment: Very interesting point, thanks! I've to review my current project codebase and rethink whether somesing could be improved in terms of design.

Comment: Thanks guys - very interesting comments but a little over my head.  I've added a comment to the original question to clarify my intentions a bit.  Any proposed approach on that type of design intent would be appreciated :)

Comment: I've thought a little more, and read a bit about the Liskov Substitution Principle. It's saying that a subclass S should be able to be substituted for a base class C without issue.  Having extra properties or methods in S doesn't sound to me like it would break this principle - I actually thought that was the reason to have subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

No, in your example, since `DocAction` is only a `DocumentAction`, you will only be able to see the properties of a `DocumentAction`, no matter which derived type of `DocumentAction` is used.